# IDS/IPS on Ubiquiti EdgeRouter

Tags: network-monitoring, ids, ips, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have changed my network setup from the default ISP device to an Ubiquiti EdgeRouter (ER-X-SFP) a while ago. Currently I’m planing to switch to an static IPv4 address. From the ISP I would also get an IPv6 Prefix.

Besides the build in firewall I would also like to use an IDS/IPS system in order to better protect my network. In general I’m really new in IDS/IDS systems an I tried to find a solution in order to use the EdgeRouter instead of buying an additional device.

I can’t find much information about this topic besides that this would not work caused by the limited DRAM of the EdgeRouter (in regard to Suricata).

I found two IDS/IPS systems which are, from my point of view, could be interesting for this use case: Suricata and Snort. Both are available as mipsel packages from Debian (EdgeMax the OS of the Edge series is based on Debian stretch afaik). To come to my question(s):

1. Could be the limited DRAM (256 MB)?
2. Could be the limited flash storage a problem (256 MB) or is the an external logging possibility instead of using the local drive?
3. Would it be an good idea to use an EdgeRouter instead of an dedicated device?
4. If somebody has practical experience I would be happy to hear about them

Thanks in advance